# Events on some part of markers are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a code that looks like this

```
var data = [tons of lat long];

/* Create the markers */
for (var i = 0; i = data.length; i++) {
    /* Put the markers */

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { 
        lat: parseFloat(lat1),
        lng: parseFloat(lng1)
    },
      map: map,
      icon: icon,
      label: {
        text: "Testing"
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: "9px"
      }
    });

    /* create popup */
    marker.content = sndformat();

     /* Put the pop up in the markers */
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    /* Marker events  On Click */
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
        /* Display popup */
        infoWindow.setContent(this.content);
        infoWindow.open(this.getMap(), this);

        /* Zoom In */
        curmarker = this.position;
        map.setCenter(curmarker);
        map.setZoom(20);

        /* If zoom out image has been clicked */
        $('#imgclick').bind('click', function() {          
          map.setCenter(default latlong);
          map.setZoom(7);
        });
    });
}
```

Now here is my question. focus on this 2

```
marker.content = sndformat();
```

and

```
function sndformat() {
    return 'a Image with a name and id called imgclick'
}
```

The sample code above works and the output of that is to create a marker with a popup that has a button on it so when i click the marker it will zoom in and when i click the image on the popup it will zoomout or go to a default area.

My problem here is that the zoom in works but the zoom out when image click not work on all buttons only some of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

```
$('#imgclick').bind('click', function() {
                      center = {lat: 12.8797, lng: 121.7740};          
                      map.setCenter(center);
                      map.setZoom(7);
                    });
```